# Sum a set of probability distributions

Tags: probability

I'm a bit rusted with probabilities, I need a bit of advice.

I have a set of independent events E1..EN, that can occur with probability p(E1)..p(En).
When Ei occurs, i can make a measurement of a value Vi, that follows a distribution for which I know the mean and variance. If Ei does not occur, Vi=0

How can I calculate the mean and variance of sum(Vi)?
Additionally, if Vi follows some law (eg. normal distribution) can I say something about sum(Vi) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_k=P(E_k)$.  Define $U_k$ as the measured value of $V_v$ when $E_k$ occurs. 
Then $S=\sum_{k=1}^n p_kU_k$
The mean $E(S)=\sum_{k=1}^n p_kE(U_k)$
Since the $E_k$ are independent, $\sigma^2(S)=\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2\sigma^2(U_k)$.

Implicit is the assumption that the $U_k$ are independent.